# Solr Performance Issues (Caching/RAM usage)

Tags: caching, solr

We are using Solr 5.2 (on windows 2012 server/jdk 1.8) for document content indexing/querying. We found that querying slows down intermittently under load condition.

In our analysis we found following two issues.

#### Solr is not effectively using caches

Whenever new document indexed, it opens new searcher and cache will become invalid (as it was associated with old Index Searcher). In our scenario, new documents are indexed very frequently (at least 10 document are indexed per minute). So effectively cache will not be useful as it will open new searcher frequently to make new documents available for searching. How can improve caching usage?

#### RAM is not utilized

We observed that Solr is using only 1-2 GB of heap even though we have assign 50 GB. Seems like it is not loading index into RAM which leads to high IO. Is it possible to configure Solr to fully load indexes in memory?  Don't find any documentation about this.

Comment: How do you add/index documents? From your description I assume that you perform a hardcommit after each addition. Could you show the piece of code that performs this or the related configuration?

Comment: As for the RAM, we have it the other way around. Could you lookup your solrconfig.xml, which `<directoryFactory ... />` you are using.